# UITextView input cursor issue in iOSsimulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, subview

I am trying to create dynamic UITextViewController for my iOS application.So from my ApplicationViewController I am trying to get the TextView.

Textview is coming properly but the input cursor for my UITextView in coming down.How to get the blue input cursor from the top?

[image]

## TextViewController.m

```
+(UITextField *)prepareUITextView
{
    UITextView *uiTextView= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
                                                          10, 80, 300, 100)];
    uiTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    uiTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    uiTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    uiTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    uiTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    uiTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [uiTextView becomeFirstResponder];
    uiTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    return uiTextView;
}
```

## ApplicationViewController.m

```
[self.view addSubview:[TextViewController prepareUITextView]];
```

Comment: I run you code in my simulator, it work prefect.

Comment: Add 1 more line with textAlignment to Left

Comment: In attribute inspector, goto Control in that alignment must be adjust as ur wish

Comment: @vishnu this is generated TextView,So I dont know that we can use attribute inspector for this also.

Comment: then u have to try this     uitextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0); adjust values as u can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
uiTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7.0,0.0,0,0.0);
```

Adjust the Top value the way you want. this will solve your issue.